# Call two threads concurrently with return

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to call two threads in parallel.
Each of them has to return a hash table.

Here my code.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<Map<Object, Map<String,Double>>> task1 = executor.submit(new GettingDataDaemon(request,0));
map = task1.get();
Future<Map<Object, Map<String,Double>>> task2 = executor.submit(new GettingDataDaemon(request,1));
map_compare = task2.get();
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
System.out.println("MAPS CREATED");
```

where the GettingDataDaemon class is:

```
public class GettingDataDaemon implements Callable<Map<Object, Map<String,Double>>> {

HttpServletRequest request;
int index;

public GettingDataDaemon(HttpServletRequest request, int index){
    this.request = request;
    this.index = index;
}

@Override
public Map<Object, Map<String,Double>> call() {

    AbstractClass absClass = new AbstractClass();
    Map<Object, Map<String,Double>> map = absClass.getData(request, index);
    System.out.println("Returning map "+(index+1)+"...");
    return map;

}
```

I tested my code but the second thread starts after the first one ended.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As established, `Future.get()` is a blocking call, so it shouldn't be called unless either the result has been calculated, or it's the only `Future` left and you don't have anything else to do besides wait.

To execute your daemons in parallel, the easiest way is to just switch some lines.

```
Future<Map<Object, Map<String,Double>>> task1 = executor.submit(new GettingDataDaemon(request,0));
Future<Map<Object, Map<String,Double>>> task2 = executor.submit(new GettingDataDaemon(request,1));
map = task1.get();
map_compare = task2.get();
executor.shutdown();
```

You also don't want to write something as silly as `while(!executor.isTerminated())`, since it will busy loop and burn up the CPU for absolutely no reason. Use `executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))` (naturally choose the timeout as you please). However in this case after `task2.get()` returns, there's no need to await for termination anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is waiting for the first task to finish due to the call of `task1.get()`. Have a look at the docs:

> V get() : Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()

Comment: Is there a way to use this approach? Could I call the two `get` after `submit`?

Comment: Yes. you can call get on futuretask instance after shutdown